# Flip a YAML file content so that the newest lines are top

Tags: linux, yaml

I have a YAML file with thousands of lines of text in it, and I want the most recent lines added to appear on the very top of the file and the oldest contents to be at the very bottom of the file, so that when I open the file I don't have to scroll down for 5 minutes to get to the bottom to be able to read the new content.

```
#current structure        #desired structure
1: oldest line            4: newest line
2: old line               3: new line 
3: new line               2: old line
4: newest line            1: oldest line
```

Comment: You can use the `tac` command in `bash` to print the lines in reverse order

Answer (score -1):

One solution, taking care of comments :

### Command

```
head -1 file; awk 'NR>1' file | sort -nr
```

### Output

```
#current structure
4: newest line
3: new line       
2: old line       
1: oldest line
```

### Finally  to overwrite file

```
head -1 file; awk 'NR>1' file | sort -nr | tee file
```

(works for small files.)

For big files :

```
 head -1 file; awk 'NR>1' file | sort -nr > temp$$
 mv temp$$ file
```

Comment: This doesn't rewrite the file, it just outputs the content of the file upsidedown in the terminal.

Comment: So, do you know Unix redirections ? I will add it

Comment: running this command it only re adjust the content once. But when i run it again i was expecting that the file gets re adjusted back to its original state. however it doesn't.

Comment: I have very less UNIX experience

Comment: Always use backups. My snippet do exactly what you asked. I would like the one that voted down to know the reason